# How to download pictures from a URL list?

Tags: scrapy, extract, scrapy-pipeline

I have a url list which contains 6129 urls and each of them is a product page and contains products picture(s). How can i go through all of them and download the pictures (one is enough from each page)?

Here is a product page:
https://homasita.hu/homasita-lampa-blade-x-ablaktorlo-gumi-par-ptfe-61cm-0119008-tk-t57138-c695

Thanks!

Comment: Visit the page. Examine the HTML for image links. Get the images in turn. You may need BS4 and 'requests' to do this work.

Comment: There's a great [external tutorial](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/download-web-page-images-python), but you will need to modify that code for your needs, mainly regarding what do you consider a valid url from which to download. Set up a loop which goes through all the links and gets the valid urls from all the pages, then download.